# Two questions about Li-Yau-Hamilton estimate

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Picture below is from [231 page](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947) . For to prove $Q\ge 0$ on $M \times (0,T)$, 
$(\partial_t -\Delta)Q \ge 0$ and $Q\ge 0$ are  needed to prove.But I can't see $Q\ge 0$ when $t=0$.

Besides, how to ensure 
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& (\partial_t -\Delta) W_a =\frac{1}{t}W_a \\
& \nabla_aW_b=0
\end{aligned}
\right.~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
& (\partial_t-\Delta)U_{ab} = 0 \\
& \nabla_aU_{bc} = \frac{1}{2}(R_{ab}W_c-R_{ac}W_b)+\frac{1}{4t}(g_{ab}W_c-g_{ac}W_b)
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
have solutions ? And $W_a$ and $U_{ab}$ are arbitrary , how to explain it ? (It is enough that the basis meets the equations ?)

Whether it is not suitable there are two questions in an question ?

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, wouldn't question at this level better fit math overflow than math stackexchange?